# Hadoop installation - Datanode running, but not showing in JPS

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

I have installed CDH3U5 on a 2 node cluster. Everything seems to run fine such as all the services, web UI, MR jobs, HDFS shell commands. However, interestingly, when I started the datanode service, it gave me an OK message that datanode is running as process say X. But when I run JPS, I do not see the label "Datanode" for the process. So the output looks like -

```
17153 TaskTracker
18908 Jps
16267
```

The process ID - 16267 is the Datanode process. All other checkpoints have passed. So this seems weird. The same thing happens on the other node in the cluster. Any insight into this behavior and if this is something that needs fixing would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
can you check the following and reply?
- web interface for namenode and what does it show there for livenode
- logfiles for datanode to see if any exception
- if datanode is pingable/ssh from namenode and viceversa

If all the above look ok I'm not sure what the problem is but to fix you can 
- stop all hadoop deamons
- delete temp directory pointed in conf/core-site.xml for both NN and DN
- format namenode
- start deamon
```